# When to reset a callbackhandler for a Service

Tags: android

i have two Activities A and B and one Service C. A starts B.

A and B:

- are binding and unbinding to the Service in `onStart()/onStop()`.
- are implementing a `Handler`-Object that works with Messages. The Handler is needed, so if C is doing Work and the Result is there, it will give back a result or message to A or B.
- are implementing a `ServiceConnection`-Object. In the Method `onServiceConnected` from the `ServiceConnection`-Object, the Handler will be given to the Service C.
- If i leave A or B, the Handler for the Service will be set to Null in `onStop()`. This is because the Activity is not active anymore, so it can not use the Result to do something for example showing a Dialog.

I have following Problem:

- If i start A and use a function from C everything works fine. Resultdialog is showing up.
- If i start B from A, also everything works fine. Resultdialog is showing up.
- Now if i press Back to go back to A, then C cannot contact A, cause the handler is still set to null. No Handler created Dialog is showing up.

I think it has to do something with the order of the lifecycle-methodcalls. `onStart()` for the new Activity is getting called before `onStop()` from the old activity.

Comment: I think i have a solution for this problem, i have to test it first and will post it later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) instead of onStart(), because onStart() is only called when the activity is initially started, or restarted.  If B becomes the foreground Activity, hiding A, onPause() will be called for A, and when A becomes the foreground Activity again (because you pressed the back button), onResume() will be called, not onStart() (unless A was deleted because of a low memory situation).

Comment: Hello, 
as what i have read and observed is, please correct me if im wrong, that onStart()/onStop() are always getting called when there is a Transition from a Activity to a new one. Because then the old Activity is not in foreground anymore. The only time that a Activity is not in foreground and only onResume()/onPause() is getting called, is when the screen gets dark and then shows up again or when a Dialog-Themed Activity shows up (i have not tested the last one).